# Excel opens asking for a date

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, input

I am creating a spreadsheet that needs to ask the user to input a date upon opening the workbook.  The answer field needs to include a valid date range that goes back 13 months.

Once a valid date has been input, it then needs to open a data folder and populate a specific matrix.

This is the first part of the project. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SU! That's a great description of a problem, but not much of a question.  How are you implementing this?  What have you got so far?   Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to ask for a date without using match.com:

```
Sub AskingForADate()
    Dim d As Date, dOld As Date
    Dim OK As Boolean
    dOld = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 13, Day(Date))
    OK = False
    While Not OK
        d = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter a date within the last 18 months", Type:=1)
        If d <= Date And d >= dOld Then
            OK = True
        Else
            MsgBox "Not valid"
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```